# A resource can be assigned to a task before it's available

Tags: ms-project, tasks, human-resources

I have a resource available from 10am to 6 pm but I can assign a task to that resource with a start time of 9:30 am. I would think that should be disallowed, or at least flagged, but it is not. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Staff and schedule management are not the same thing. I do not know if MSProject, or other tools, has the functionality to flag something like this, but as a PM, or scheduler, you shouldn't want to flag it. You should be able to schedule the work package to begin when you want it to begin. Whether it begins at exactly 9:30 am or 10:00 am is a degree of precision, and noise quite frankly, that you wouldn't want to deal with in a schedule. An employee's start time would contribute to variances, perhaps, but that is one variable of thousands of variables that will cause variances so that sort of thing is not worth controlling. Furthermore, if the start time of an employee is interfering with the work, then you have the opportunity to change the assigned employee for that package.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Maybe I was not clear. The task start and end times are fixed along with the employee end times so we are using or trying to use project as like a reservation system. The employee starts at 10 am and I have established their working and non-working hours in project. If I add that person to a task that starts at 9:30 I would expect some pop up or icon to show a conflict. for example it works fine if the employee  does not work thursday but I assign a task for thursday I get a little conflict in the far left column. It does seem to enforce the day but not the time.

Comment: Oh, okay. There are folks here who are MS Project experts. Maybe they will jump in to see if they can provide a solution.